# Two directives use true scope , one is parent of the other , why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is Plunkhttp://plnkr.co/edit/MlsOkwcrrHc2fnvZrWPI?p=preview.
(please ignore test and amp directives, they are useless)

## *CLOSED*

Reason for closing this question:
I add more log and add variable to child scope and find that first and second **share same child scope**. So this is my fault to come out this pointless question. 
**But** there is one thing I found: If I use `scope.$emit()` at a directive(second at this plunk), the other directive which use same scope(first at this plunk) will receive the event while parent will receive as expected. And If use `scope.$parent.$emit()`, only parent will receive.

## HTML

`<div first second></div>`

I emit `second-directive` event from second directive:

```
    link: function(scope,ele,attrs) {
      console.log('second directive --------------\n');
      console.log(scope);  // log scope of second directive here
      scope.$emit('second-directive', 'from second');
    }
```

And catch event from first directive and main controller:

## main

```
    $scope.$on('second-directive',function(event,args){
        console.log('get event at main -------------\n');
        console.log(event);
        console.log(args);
      });
```

## directive first

```
    $scope.$on('second-directive',function(event,args){
        console.log('get event at first directive -------------\n');
        console.log(event);
        console.log(args);
      });
```

You can see log message at console, and find this:

scope of second directive have parent(first directive) and grandparent(main). Family tree like this:

```
main
|- first
    |-second
```

but I make first directive and second directive use `scope: true` both, so they should create new child scope of main. The family tree should be like this:

```
main
|- first
|- second
```

Do I misunderstand " `scope:true` is used to create child-scope " ?
Someone can explain this and help here? Thanks :)

Comment: You probably need to put some relevant code in your question.

Comment: [Understanding-Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).hope this can help your.

Comment: @jfriend00, although, you can read all my code from plunk. But I will take your advise. And add more detail and code. Thanks.

Comment: @Kain, thanks. I will read that.

Comment: @Kain, according [Understanding-Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), ` If more than one directive (on the same DOM element) requests a new scope, only one new child scope is created.`. My plunk hit this condition, then the family should like this:

Comment: `
main

|- child(first and second)
`
But the result is not.